WebServer HTTP Response Output Stream
Handles streaming of the response body.
In construction you either pass a content-length value and the stream will allow you to send that many bites before cutting you off. Or you can pass the transfer-encoding type in which case the stream will automatically convert the input into the appropriate output stream underneath (currently only support chunked but plan to expand).
StreamOutput.h
#ifndef THORSANVIL_NISSE_NISSEHTTP_STREAMOUTPUT_H
#define THORSANVIL_NISSE_NISSEHTTP_STREAMOUTPUT_H

#include "NisseHTTPConfig.h"
#include "Util.h"
#include <iostream>

namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP
{

class StreamBufOutput: public std::streambuf
{
    public:
        using Complete = std::function<void()>;
        typedef std::streambuf::traits_type traits;
        typedef traits::int_type            int_type;
        typedef traits::char_type           char_type;
    private:
        static std::streamsize constexpr chunkBufferSize = 1024;
        std::streamsize     remaining;
        std::streambuf*     buffer;
        bool                chunked;
        bool                firstChunk;
        std::vector<char>   chunkBuffer;
    public:
        ~StreamBufOutput();
        StreamBufOutput();
        StreamBufOutput(std::ostream& stream, std::size_t length;
        StreamBufOutput(std::ostream& stream, Encoding encoding);
        StreamBufOutput(StreamBufOutput&& move)                   noexcept;
        StreamBufOutput& operator=(StreamBufOutput&& move)        noexcept;
        StreamBufOutput(StreamBufOutput const&)                   = delete;
        StreamBufOutput& operator=(StreamBufOutput const&)        = delete;

        void swap(StreamBufOutput& other) noexcept;
        friend void swap(StreamBufOutput& lhs, StreamBufOutput& rhs)   {lhs.swap(rhs);}

        void done();

    protected:
        virtual int             sync() override;

        // Write:
        virtual std::streamsize xsputn(char_type const*,std::streamsize) override;
        virtual int_type        overflow(int_type = traits::eof()) override;

    private:
        void            checkBuffer();
        void            outputChunkSize(std::streamsize size);
        char            toHex(int digit);
        void            sendAllData(char const* s, std::streamsize size);

        std::streamsize xsputnChunked(char_type const*,std::streamsize);
        std::streamsize xsputnLength(char_type const*,std::streamsize);
        int_type        overflowChunked(int_type = traits::eof());
        int_type        overflowLength(int_type = traits::eof());
        void            dumpBuffer();
};
class StreamOutput: public std::ostream
{
    StreamBufOutput    buffer;
    public:
        StreamOutput()
            : std::ostream(nullptr)
            , buffer()
        {}
        StreamOutput(std::ostream& stream, std::size_t length)
            : std::ostream(nullptr)
            , buffer(stream, length)
        {
            rdbuf(&buffer);
        }
        StreamOutput(std::ostream& stream, Encoding encoding)
            : std::ostream(nullptr)
            , buffer(stream, encoding)
        {
            rdbuf(&buffer);
        }

        void addBuffer(StreamBufOutput&& newBuffer)
        {
            buffer = std::move(newBuffer);
            rdbuf(&buffer);
            clear();
        }
};

}

#endif

StreamOutput.cpp
#include "StreamOutput.h"

using namespace ThorsAnvil::Nisse::NisseHTTP;

StreamBufOutput::~StreamBufOutput()
{
    done();
}

StreamBufOutput::StreamBufOutput()
    : remaining(0)
    , buffer(nullptr)
    , chunked(false)
    , firstChunk(false)
    , chunkBuffer(0)
{}

StreamBufOutput::StreamBufOutput(std::ostream& stream, std::size_t length)
    : remaining(length)
    , buffer(stream.rdbuf())
    , chunked(false)
    , firstChunk(false)
    , chunkBuffer(0)
{}

StreamBufOutput::StreamBufOutput(std::ostream& stream, Encoding /*encoding*/)
    : remaining(chunkBufferSize)
    , buffer(stream.rdbuf())
    , chunked(true)
    , firstChunk(true)
    , chunkBuffer(chunkBufferSize)
{}

StreamBufOutput::StreamBufOutput(StreamBufOutput&& move) noexcept
    : remaining(std::exchange(move.remaining, 0))
    , buffer(std::exchange(move.buffer, nullptr))
    , chunked(std::exchange(move.chunked, false))
    , firstChunk(std::exchange(move.firstChunk, false))
    , chunkBuffer(std::move(move.chunkBuffer))
{}

StreamBufOutput& StreamBufOutput::operator=(StreamBufOutput&& move) noexcept
{
    remaining   = 0;
    buffer      = nullptr;
    chunked     = false;
    firstChunk  = false;
    chunkBuffer.resize(0);

    swap(move);

    return *this;
}

void StreamBufOutput::swap(StreamBufOutput& other) noexcept
{
    std::streambuf::swap(other);

    using std::swap;
    swap(remaining,     other.remaining);
    swap(buffer,        other.buffer);
    swap(chunked,       other.chunked);
    swap(firstChunk,    other.firstChunk);
    swap(chunkBuffer,   other.chunkBuffer);
}

// Control:
int StreamBufOutput::sync()
{
    checkBuffer();
    dumpBuffer();
    return buffer->pubsync();
}

void StreamBufOutput::dumpBuffer()
{
    if (chunked)
    {
        std::streamsize     chunkSize = chunkBufferSize - remaining;
        if (chunkSize != 0)
        {
            outputChunkSize(chunkSize);
            sendAllData(&chunkBuffer[0], chunkBufferSize - remaining);
            sendAllData("\r\n", 2);
            remaining = chunkBufferSize;
        }
    }
}

void StreamBufOutput::done()
{
    if (chunked)
    {
        dumpBuffer();
        sendAllData("0\r\n", 3);
        remaining = 0;
        chunked = false;
    }
}

void StreamBufOutput::sendAllData(char const* s, std::streamsize size)
{
    while (size != 0)
    {
        std::streamsize sent = buffer->sputn(s, size);
        s    += sent;
        size -= sent;
    }
}

char StreamBufOutput::toHex(int digit)
{
    return digit >= 10 ? 'A' + (digit - 10)
                       : '0' + digit;
}

void StreamBufOutput::outputChunkSize(std::streamsize size)
{
    bool started   = false;
    for (auto x: { 4096, 256, 16, 1})
    {
        int digit = size / x;
        if (digit != 0 || started)
        {
            started = true;
            buffer->sputc(toHex(digit));
        }
        size = size - (digit * x);
    }
    sendAllData("\r\n", 2);
}

// Write:
std::streamsize StreamBufOutput::xsputnChunked(char_type const* s,std::streamsize count)
{
    if (count > remaining)
    {
        std::streamsize     chunkSize = chunkBufferSize - remaining + count;
        outputChunkSize(chunkSize);
        sendAllData(&chunkBuffer[0], chunkBufferSize - remaining);
        sendAllData(s, count);
        sendAllData("\r\n", 2);
        remaining = chunkBufferSize;
    }
    else
    {
        std::copy(s, s + count, std::begin(chunkBuffer) + ( chunkBufferSize - remaining));
        remaining -= count;
    }
    return count;
}

std::streamsize StreamBufOutput::xsputnLength(char_type const* s,std::streamsize count)
{
    std::streamsize result = 0;
    while (remaining != 0 && count != 0)
    {
        std::size_t max = std::min(count, remaining);
        std::streamsize sent = buffer->sputn(s, max);
        s           += sent;
        count       -= sent;
        result      += sent;
        remaining   -= sent;
    }
    if (remaining == 0)
    {
        sync();
    }
    return result;
}
std::streamsize StreamBufOutput::xsputn(char_type const* s,std::streamsize count)
{
    if (chunked) {
        return xsputnChunked(s, count);
    }
    else {
        return xsputnLength(s, count);
    }
}

StreamBufOutput::int_type StreamBufOutput::overflowChunked(int_type ch)
{
    if (ch != traits::eof())
    {
        char_type v = ch;
        xsputnChunked(&v, 1);
    }
    return 1;
}

StreamBufOutput::int_type StreamBufOutput::overflowLength(int_type ch)
{
    if (ch == traits::eof()) {
        return remaining == 0 ? traits::eof() : 1;
    }
    int_type result = traits::eof();
    if (remaining != 0)
    {
        if ((result = buffer->sputc(ch)) != traits::eof()) {
            --remaining;
        }
        if (remaining == 0) {
            sync();
        }
    }
    return result;
}

StreamBufOutput::int_type StreamBufOutput::overflow(int_type ch)
{
    if (chunked) {
        return overflowChunked(ch);
    }
    else {
        return overflowLength(ch);
    }
}

